# SQL Developer & Oracle 11g: Undefined error

Tags: java, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, ojdbc

*Initial data:*
**Database:** Oracle 11g
**IDE:** SQL Developer, SQL Plus
**LISTENER.ora:**
[image]
**TNSNAMES.ora:**
[image]

The output of the command **LSNRCTL status** and **LSNRCTL services:**
[image]
[image]

**LISTENER.log,** when I connect using **SQL Developer** (*ERROR* connection)

```
Wed Sep 16 17:17:32 2015
16-СЕН-2015 17:17:32 * 1153
TNS-01153: Сбой при обработке строки: (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=testdb)(CID=(PROGRAM=SQL Developer)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER="Q<0)))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
 NL-00303: синтаксическая ошибка в NV-строке
```

[image]

**LISTENER.log**, when I connect using **Eclipse:**(*ERROR* connection!)

```
    Wed Sep 16 18:55:02 2015
    16-СЕН-2015 18:55:02 * 1153
    TNS-01153: Сбой при обработке строки: (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=testdb)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER="Q<0)))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
NL-00303: синтаксическая ошибка в NV-строке
```

[image]

**LISTENER.log**, when I connect using **SQL Plus:**(*GOOD* connection!)

```
Wed Sep 16 00:40:18 2015
16-СЕН-2015 00:40:18 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=testdb)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\server\bin\sqlplus.exe)(HOST=ASUS-PC)(USER=????))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=59460)) * establish * testdb * 0
```

[image]

*My question:*
**Please tell me why this problem appears? How to solve it? I really need your help(**

Comment: Your SQL\*Plus log entry is much earlier. Have you manually modified and restarted the listener since then? The hashed-out line in your listener.ora looks suspicious. Does restarting the listener service help? If not can you discard and recreate the listener through netca?

Comment: @AlexPoole, Hi! Thanks for your answer! 
1) SQL Plus connects always. But SQL Developer with the same parameters does not connect. 
2) In the example, can be an empty string 
3) Restarting the services does not help. (Can you send the result of the command LSNRCTL status and  LSNRCTL service) 
4) How to create a listener through NETCA?

Comment: Does SQL Developer connect if you specify the testdb service rather than SID? (Which is what you're doing with the Easy Connect syntax you're using for SQL\*Plus; you are not currently using the same parameters)

Comment: @AlexPoole, 1) If I enter the service name as testdb, then I get a new error: "The Network Adapter could not establish the connection" 2) 
What do you mean when you said that I do not use the same parameters?

Comment: SID and service name are not the same thing (though they may have the same value). Your SQL Developer connection is using the SID, as is  Eclipse - you can tell from the log message, but also from the URL which ends in `:testdb`. For SQL\*Plus you're using `/testdb`; if you used that from Eclipse you would be using the service name. Is this all on the same PC?

Comment: @AlexPoole,   
0) I have displayed the output of LSNRCTL status and LSNRCTL services 1) I Have a SID and Service name are the same. `testdb`it's SID and Service name  2) Yes, it's all on one computer.

Comment: @AlexPoole What data do I need to put in the connection window of SQL Developer?